# Django: Custom ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on a payment processor (in django 1.7) and I'm having trouble with these 2 models: `Transaction` and `Event`. They are in a custom many2one relationship in the sense that the field `reference` is unique in `Transaction` and `Event` entries having the same `reference` field belong to the `Transaction` with that `reference`. I was wondering if there a clean way to represent this in django.

I removed the `reference` field from the Event model, and added this transaction field:

```
    transaction = models.ForeignKey('Transaction',db_column='reference',
 to_field='reference',db_constraint=False, related_query_name='events')
```

This way I was able to access the transaction object from the event and use it nicely in queries, but now I can't access the `reference` field form an `Event` instance. This is weird since with a normal `ForeignKey` you're able to use both `object` and `object_id`.

Also I had to fake out the generated migration:(.

Is there a clean way to this?

Comment: Please be more specific than "now I can't access". Are you trying `event.transaction`, `event.transaction_id`, or `event.reference`? Are they raising `AttributeErrors`?

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry about that. I haven't been able to access `event.reference` Ideally I would like a solution where I would be able to use the `reference` field just like as it was explicitly declared in the model.

Comment: @user81269 The `transaction` field refers to the `reference` column, i.e. data from the old `reference` field. If you want to access that data with `event.reference` you need to name the foreign key `reference` or set a property that returns `self.transaction`.

Comment: @knbk `event.transaction` in this case returns the `transaction` model instance and I have no way accessing the data in the `reference` column. I'm looking for a solution where the following statements are all valid

`event.transcation` -> returns a Transaction instance

`Event.objects.filter(transaction__in=transactions)`, where `transactions` 
is a queryset from `Transaction`.


`event.reference` -> returns an integer


`Event.objects.filter(reference=123123`)`
thanks.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry `event.transaction_id` actually returns the data in the column, `event.transaction` returns the Transaction object and `event.reference` throws an attribute error. Is there a way to be able to use `event.reference` instead of `event.transaction_id`? Thanks, `transaction_id` was a massive help already.

Comment: You'll need to make `event.reference` a property, i.e. a method that returns `self.transaction_id` with the `@property` decorator. Is there a particular reason why you want to access it through `event.reference`?